# Завести внешний и локальный статический IP

Tags: сервер, сеть

У меня такой вопрос.Я когда то задал вопрос как создать хостинг сервер в своем ПК. Получил ответ.Пункт 1-завести внешний статический IP и локальный(настроить DCHP). Вопрос такой:Я могу сам это настроить/завести или надо у ISP купить? Поможете буду рад!

Comment: если у вас один сервер, то DHCP и локальные адреса вам не нужны. А внешний статический ip конечно получаете у провайдера

Comment: А DHCP что такое можете сказать по кратце? Блогадарю вас

Comment: Сервер раздающий ip адреса. Когда у вас в настройках сети стоит "получить настройки ip автоматически" они получают их от dhcp сервера

Comment: Я понял вас блогадарю пишите если хотите как ответ я нажму на флаг удачи вам!